# NPM error: Error: No such module at Object.<anonymous>

Tags: macos, node.js, npm

I'm running into this problem after installing node 0.6.6

https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/1842

I'm not sure how I would go about executing the solution in that post.

my err

```
Error: No such module
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/config-defs.js:5:21)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to uninstall the old version of `npm`. You can see how to uninstall it in [npm's github page](https://github.com/isaacs/npm).

Comment: `sudo npm uninstall npm -g` throws the same error im already seeing. 
Where would I run `sudo make uninstall`? Thanks for the help

Comment: You do that where you download the code and run `make install` inside the code directory. If you still have the directory you can just `cd` there and `sudo make uninstall`. If none of the two works you can just nuke it by running `rm` on the directory where you installed it.

Comment: @FedericoBuiles What do you mean by "nuke"? (_you can just nuke it by running rm_) I wonder, is "nuking" some npm term? or just a buzzword?

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same issue upgrading from Node.JS 0.4 to 0.8, the answer above was of no help whatsoever. The Github pages don't have any instructions on this specific issue either. What helped me was the following:

The OSX Node.JS package installer erroneously does not remove the old 0.4 npm installation in /usr/bin, which then conflicts with the new 0.8 one in /usr/local/bin. It just overwrites whatever is there already. I nuked the old one by deleting it, but to make sure, I decided a clean install would be better:

`curl https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo clean=yes sh`

There was one last problem: after the install, even though a `which npm` correctly returns `/usr/local/bin/npm`, bash kept trying to execute from /usr/bin. This is because on OSX, bash has hashed the executable name. The hashing saves repeated searches of all directories in your PATH every time you execute common programs. A `hash -r` at the command line took care of this issue.

Comment: can you please help? i have the same error and tried to follow your instructions step by step, also wrote hash -r but still having the dreaded "no such module". I dont understand this, its insanely frustrating. thank you in advance

Comment: @Axel What do you mean by "nuked"? (_I nuked the old one by deleting it_) I wonder, is "nuking" some npm term? or just a buzzword?